# How can I set a label's value equal to another without an action?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

I am currently working on an iOS application (Swift) in Xcode for my work study position at school. To highlight the background of the portion mentioned in this question: The user goes through a series of pages to basically grade the student on their performance through nursing simulations. I need there to be an extra tab where the user can verify the grading that has been entered just simply by showing the number of things they selected that were done in the scenario.

Basically I have a tabbed view controller with three tabs. The first tab has switches the user can turn on or off to add or subtract to a variable, "WASH". The second tab is the same but it adds/subtracts to a variable, "ID". The third tab is to confirm the values. So if the student does 2/3 for Washing their hands and 4/5 of checking the patient's ID, it should be viewed here.

here is basically the code I have for every switch

```
@IBOutlet weak var IDTOTAL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CHECKID1: UISwitch!    
@IBAction func ID1(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if(CHECKID1.isOn) {
            ID = ID + 1
            total = total + 1
            IDTOTAL.text = String(ID)
        }
        else {
            ID = ID - 1
            total = total - 1
            IDTOTAL.text = String(ID)
        }

    }
```

Please note that the variables ID and total are global variables. Currently, IDTOTAL is on the same view controller as the switch and this works fine. I tried to add another label on the confirm view controller called "IDTOTAL2" and tried setting it to a value with "IDTOTAL2.text = String(ID)" but this throws an error.

How do I go about making the label on the last page update its value without requiring the user to push a button to initiate an action?

EDIT: [Please refer to this picture to see the error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am5kk.png)

Comment: Why would you want a button? Just do it in you event handler when the user selects the switch? Or you could do it in the summary controller's `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: I wanted to do it in the event handler when the user selects the switch, but this throws an error. I'm not entirely certain what you mean by summary controller?

Comment: What do you mean by `universal variable`?

Comment: global variable! sorry, I'll change that right now.

Comment: By "summary controller" I was referring to the one where you show a summary of how many switches were switched. Can we have the error you are seeing please?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen I added a screenshot above to show you the error. I included the storyboard and connection to ALLTOTAL (which I changed from TOTAL just because I have redone it about 8 times). The app crashes when I try to turn on the "Student Washed Hands", or "CHECKWASH1" switch.

Comment: @Eric Aya thank you. I understand I can't expect to get answers immediately. I'm frustrated because every single question I ask, someone has a problem with. I have no one to ask these questions to and I want to accurately use the site so I'll work on that.

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe I understand. Sometimes it's not easy to comply with all the site's rules. Don't be discouraged - we're judging the questions and the answers, not the people who post them. :) Continue to learn how the site works, post good questions and you will see that you will organically get good answers. Good luck!

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe It looks like you forgot to connect your `ALLTOTAL` property to your label in interface builder, hence it is nil when you try to reference it. Notice the little `+` immediately to the left of the property definition, hover over that and drag it to the label in IB to "wire it up".

Answer (score 0):

You can update your labels in the `viewDidAppear` function of your third tab, since it gets triggered every time you switch from another tab to this one. Simply add:

`override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //update your labels here
    }`

Comment: This throws an error, Its the same error as above. :(